# startActivity illegal start of type

Tags: android, android-intent, android-maps

As of this morning I've tried to put together enough knowledge to produce a very basic app to demonstrate a concept. The idea is to display google maps, the user presses on where they want to add a marker, then a screen pops up where they can fill out more information that is then displayed when someone taps that marker.

This is what I got from the Android Studio base.

```
 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 

OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

private void setMapLongClick(final GoogleMap map) {
    map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.z
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Move the camera to Delft
    LatLng delft = new LatLng(52.003569, 4.372987);
    Float zoom = 15f;
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(delft, zoom));
    setMapLongClick(mMap);
}
}
```

I tried adding this

```
    private void setMarkerClick(final GoogleMap map) {
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    });
}
```

But I get and "illegal start of type" error. Am I doing this completely wrong?
Is there an easier way to add information to a marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should use it.

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing `this` as first argument when creating the `Intent` might not work since it refers to the `OnMarkerClickListener` anonymous class and not to the `packageContext`. Here's my suggestion, give `MapsActivity.this` as reference:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call

```
this.startActivity(intent);
```

inside an anonymous class as startActivity is not a method of the anonymous class but of the enclosing activity. Therefore you should use

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Also use the proper anonymous implementation.